# Scala and dropWhile

Tags: scala

I'm a senior in HS and a newbie to functional programming and Scala.  I was trying out a few constructs in Scala REPL and needed some guidance for the return responses

```
//Defined a tuple

scala> val x =(2.0, 3.0, 1)
x: (Double, Double, Int) = (2.0,3.0,1)

//This made sense to me.  Result is a list of values that are of type Ints
scala> x.productIterator.dropWhile(_.isInstanceOf[Double]).toList
res1: List[Any] = List(1)

**//This DID NOT make sense to me.  Why are Double values included?**
scala> x.productIterator.dropWhile(_.isInstanceOf[Int]).toList
res0: List[Any] = List(2.0, 3.0, 1)


//filter operator seems to work
scala> x.productIterator.toList.filter(x => x.isInstanceOf[Double])
res7: List[Any] = List(2.0, 3.0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Iterator.dropWhile`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@dropWhile(p:A=%3EBoolean):Iterator[A]) will drop any value as long as it matches the provided predicate, and return the remainder of the iterator:

> Skips longest sequence of elements of this iterator which satisfy
>   given predicate p, and returns an iterator of the remaining elements.

The provided predicate you passed *fails* for the first element, which is of type `Double`, hence it the entire iterator which you materialize to a `List[A]`.

If, for example, you chose to drop while `isInstanceOf[Double]`, you'd receive a list with a single element `1`:

```
scala> x.productIterator.dropWhile(_.isInstanceOf[Double]).toList
res13: List[Any] = List(1)
```